# Polymer Paper-Item - Can't change the gray selected background for <paper-item>

Tags: polymer

I can't seem to change the selected background color of gray  for the , once it's used in a template. I am able to call the mix-ins and change the selected background color when  is not used in a template. Please help!

```
  <autocomplete-suggestions
id="filter-suggestions"
for="filter-input"
source="[[suggestionsSource]]"
min-length="0"
text-property="title">

<template autocomplete-custom-template>

  <paper-item class="suggestion" on-tap="_onSelect" id$="[[_getSuggestionId(index)]]">

  <style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-item: {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-family: 'Muli', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif !important;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: initial;
      color:#3F5364;
    };
    --paper-item-focused: {
    background: white;
    };
    --paper-item-focused-before: {
    background: white;
    };
  }
  </style>

    <p class= "suggestion-type">
      [[item.title]]
    </p>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.description]]" restamp="true">
      <small class="suggestion-value">
      [[item.description]]</small>
    </template>

  </paper-item>

</template>
```